# How to Copy the entire folder contents to another folder using PUTTY

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

How to Copy the entire folder contents (including sub-folders and their contents) to another folder using PUTTY? Is there any command for that?

Comment: Do you want to copy the files to another system, or simply within the same system?

Answer (score 7):

**Linux**

use `cp` command for this

for example :

```
cp -r /home/hope/files/* /home/hope/backup
```

**Windows**

use XCopy

**For example:**

```
xcopy c:\temp3 /e
```

- [Reference](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000838.htm)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is pscp.
It can be found on the same website as putty : http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/
Have fun!

EDIT : I presume that your trying to get the files from one system to another, hence the use of putty.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a bash shell you can use the following command:

`cp -r /home/dir_to_copy .` - Copies `dir_to_copy` and all its contents (sub-directories and files) to the current directory.

`cp -r dir_to_copy/* bak_dir` - Copies just the contents (sub-directories and files) of `dir_to_copy` to a backup directory named `bak_dir`, however `dir_to_copy` is not copied.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @gourav I'm assuming that you are using Putty to log in into a Linux box.